# Why does createWebviewWithConfiguration not change the displayed view when window.open is called?

Tags: objective-c, wkwebview, window.open

I'm quite new to WKWebView and am struggling with this problem where my current view doesnt change when invoking windows.open from javascript see below...

```
function logo_click() {
    window.open(some_valid_url);//url is valid www.google.com for example
}
```

I'm quite sure that this function is hit since I stepped on it using Safari Tech Preview. And I'm even getting the breakpoint in my createWebviewWithConfiguration() function in xcode obj-c when logo_click is invoked,

```
-(WKWebView*)webView:(WKWebView )webView createWebViewWithConfiguration:(nonnull WKWebViewConfiguration )inConfig forNavigationAction:(nonnull WKNavigationAction )navigationAction windowFeatures:(nonnull WKWindowFeatures )windowFeatures
{
 _webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame configuration:inConfig];

 if (!navigationAction.targetFrame.isMainFrame) {
  [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
  [self.webView loadRequest:navigationAction.request];
  //[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.com"]]];
 }

 return _webView;
}
```

I even tried hardcoding google.com to see if it can navigate from there but my displayed view is still the previous one. I already checked the tutorial on

[iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/122635-wkwebview-wont-open-external-links.html](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/122635-wkwebview-wont-open-external-links.html)

but my view still doesn't change. What could I be missing?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it using the following code...

```
-(WKWebView*)webView:(WKWebView *)webView createWebViewWithConfiguration:(nonnull WKWebViewConfiguration *)inConfig forNavigationAction:(nonnull WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction windowFeatures:(nonnull WKWindowFeatures *)windowFeatures
{
    [_webView removeFromSuperview];

    _webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame configuration:inConfig];

    if (!navigationAction.targetFrame.isMainFrame) {
        //[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
        NSURLRequest* req = navigationAction.request;
        [self.webView loadRequest:req];
    }

    _webView.navigationDelegate = self;
    _webView.UIDelegate = self;

    _webView.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    [self.view addSubview:_webView];

    return _webView;
}
```